# What is Qt for boost::promise<T>?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost

I see that Qt has [future](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuture.html) class that is direct analog for [boost::future](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) but what is qt for [boost::promise](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.promise)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boost::promises are means of setting values in futures. In Qt, you *can't* set futures, you can *only* return them. That's the only way of "setting" data in a future.

So, in order to set data on a future, you have to return it from a function that was invoked by `QtConcurrent::run`. To do this, you'd use any of Qt's mechanisms for communicating between threads -- events, mutex-protected variables, etc. You have to tell the thread that runs the code that would return a future that given future is to be returned. That's the only way of achieving what a promise would do.

Alas, if you want to go into the undocumented territory, then the following code does what `boost::promise::setValue` would:

```
QFuture<int> f;
int i = 1;
...
f.d.reportResult(&i);
// or
f.d.reportFinished(&i);
```

I haven't bothered checking if it works (yet).

Comment: The documentation for the `d` member says `// Warning: the d pointer is not documented and is considered private.`, so this probably isn't the way to go.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge It's a way to go if you choose to go that way, but of course the preferred solution is in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: Using `QFutureInterface` (like in the other answer) is probably the better option if none of the QtConcurrent helpers meet your needs.  It seems to be treated as semi-public and not going to change until Qt 6 at the earliest: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-July/022572.html

Answer (score 10):

Constructing my own QFuture as shown in the accepted answer did not work for me.  At first it seemed like it was working, but in my testing I realized it was not blocking the caller. Whoops!  So I dug into the code a little further and found that QFutureInterface is what you want to use as your 'promise'.  Like boost::promise, QFutureInterface is what you interact with in your worker thread, and it is a factory for QFutures.

So here's what I've been doing in Qt 4.8 (not sure if this is applicable to later versions).

```
QFutureInterface<QVariant> promise;
promise.reportStarted();
...
promise.reportResult(someVariant);
promise.reportFinished();
```

Then in the client thread, assuming you have access to the QFutureInterface 'promise'

```
QVariant result = promise.future().result();
```

The `future()` call is a factory method for creating a QFuture bound to your QFutureInterface.  You should be able to get the QFuture and call `result()` on it later if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Qt analog but there are a few community libraries implementing promises (or similar patterns):

- Ben Lau's AsyncFuture ([benlau/asyncfuture](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture))
  Based on the undocumented `QFutureInterface` mentioned in [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22205495/490560).
  And it's not exactly a promise pattern but rather an observer pattern.
- Benoit Walter's QtPromise ([bwalter/qt-promise](https://github.com/bwalter/qt-promise))
  Partially based on Ben Lau's AsyncFuture.
- Simon Brunel's QtPromise ([simonbrunel/qtpromise](https://github.com/simonbrunel/qtpromise))
- My QtPromise ([julrich/QtPromise](https://gitlab.com/julrich/QtPromise))
  Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Promises for Qt are now also available with QML/JavaScript btw: https://v-play.net/updates/release-2-18-1-javascript-promises-for-rest-services-tinder-swipe-material-cards-qml-qsortfilterproxymodel-qml-youtube-player

Here is some example code:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0

App {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
    var p2 = 1337;
    var p3 = HttpRequest
    .get("http://httpbin.org/get")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.body;
    });

    var p4 = Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]);

    p4.then(function(values) {
      console.log(values[0]); // 3
      console.log(values[1]); // 1337
      console.log(values[2]); // resp.body
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this library that is **highly integrated with Qt** and implements *javascript-like* promises:

https://github.com/juangburgos/QDeferred

It allows to create a thread-safe async API as follows:

```
multiplyNumbersInThread(3, 4)
.fail([](int res) {
    Q_UNUSED(res);
    qDebug() << "multiplyPositiveNumbers failed!";
})
.done([](int res) {
    qDebug() << "multiplyPositiveNumbers succeded! Result :" << res;
});
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: You should mention that you are the author of this library.
See also [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), namely the paragraph "Avoid overt self-promotion.": "However, you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers."